# Issue when reading audio with Qt in pull method

Tags: linux, qt, audio, multimedia

I'm trying to read audio from sound card with Qt and save it on a file.

The initialization of the file and QAudioInput is done as the following:

```
QFile m_file;
QByteArray m_buffer(16 * 1024, 0);
m_file.setFileName("record.wav");
m_file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

m_audioInput = new QAudioInput(m_device, m_format, this);
```

If I try to use push method, then the sound seems to be recorded OK.

```
m_audioInput->start(&m_file);
```

If however I try to use the pull method, then the sound is not recorded OK (It seems some chunks are missing)

```
m_deviceIn = m_audioInput->start();
connect(m_deviceIn, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readMore()));

void AudioIn::readMore()
{
    qint64 len = m_audioInput->bytesReady();
    if (len > BufferSize)
        len = BufferSize;
    qint64 l = m_deviceIn->read(m_buffer.data(), len);
    if (l > 0) {
        if (m_file.write(m_buffer.constData(), l) != l)
            qInfo()<< "Error write to file";
    }
}
```

can anyone explain why the pull method didn't work well?

Comment: Try to read in chunks of size `QAudioInput::periodSize()`.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but didn't solve the issue.